# MariaDB/MySQL TO_SECONDS and AGGREGATE functions

Tags: mysql, aggregate, mariadb

I want to use TO_SECONDS with aggregate functions (AVG, COUNT) to summarize my table. However, the result was not what I expected. Here is an example table:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from mytable;
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | ts                  | val  |
+----+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 2016-01-01 01:02:03 |    1 |
|  2 | 2016-01-01 01:02:04 |    2 |
|  3 | 2016-01-01 01:02:04 |    3 |
|  4 | 2016-01-01 01:02:05 |    4 |
|  5 | 2016-01-01 01:02:05 |    5 |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

Query #1 (OK):

```
MariaDB [test]> select to_seconds(ts) as tsec from mytable;
+-------------+
| tsec        |
+-------------+
| 63618829323 |
| 63618829324 |
| 63618829324 |
| 63618829325 |
| 63618829325 |
+-------------+
```

Query #2 (?):

```
MariaDB [test]> select to_seconds(ts) as tsec, avg(val) mval from mytable group by tsec;
+------------+------+
| tsec       | mval |
+------------+------+
| 2147483647 |    3 |
+------------+------+
```

Expected result:

```
+-------------+------+
| tsec        | mval |
+-------------+------+
| 63618829323 |    1 |
| 63618829324 |  2.5 |
| 63618829325 |  4.5 |
+-------------+------+
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17616a/6 
MariaDB version> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Of course I can use other DATE/TIME functions (UNIX_TIMESTAMP, etc) to perform the task. However, I want to know why the result is different. 
What am I missing? Do I misunderstood the usage of TO_SECONDS?

Comment: This would appear to be a data type problem.  The return value is being treated as an integer rather than a big int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange data type problem.  The following does work:

```
select cast(to_seconds(ts) as decimal(20, 0)) as tsec, avg(val)
from mytable
group by tsec;
```

I don't know why the return value of `to_seconds()` would be large enough to store the value when you select it, but then gets converted to an integer when you use `group by`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer why this happens, but confirm that this still happens in MySQL ver. 5.7.32, and suggest a (kludgy) workaround.

Example:

```
create table Foo (t datetime);
insert into Foo values('2020-01-01 00:00:01');
insert into Foo values('2020-01-02 00:00:01');
insert into Foo values('2020-01-03 00:00:01');
select t, to_seconds(t) from Foo;
+---------------------+---------------+
| t                   | to_seconds(t) |
+---------------------+---------------+
| 2020-01-01 00:00:01 |   63745056001 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:01 |   63745142401 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:01 |   63745228801 |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

So far so good. Now, use `group by`:

```
select t, to_seconds(t) from Foo group by t;
+---------------------+---------------+
| t                   | to_seconds(t) |
+---------------------+---------------+
| 2020-01-01 00:00:01 |    2147483647 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:01 |    2147483647 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:01 |    2147483647 |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

The `to_seconds(t)` value for each row becomes 2147483647, which is equal to 2^31-1, i.e. the largest positive value representable by a signed 4-byte integer. This looks like some kind of data conversion problem inside the MySQL server, in a situation where it ought not occur.

Essentially the same problem was reported as a MySQL bug in March 2019 (
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94612 ), but no activity, other than an acknowledgement, has been added to that bug report since.

Interestingly, the problem is obviated if instead of `to_seconds(t)` we use **`to_seconds(max(t))`**, or **`max(to_seconds(t))`** (which, theoretically, should produce the same result, since we group on `t` anyway):

```
 select t, to_seconds(t), max(t), to_seconds(max(t)), max(to_seconds(t)) from Foo group by t;
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| t                   | to_seconds(t) | max(t)              | to_seconds(max(t)) | max(to_seconds(t)) |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2020-01-01 00:00:01 |    2147483647 | 2020-01-01 00:00:01 |        63745056001 |        63745056001 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:01 |    2147483647 | 2020-01-02 00:00:01 |        63745142401 |        63745142401 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:01 |    2147483647 | 2020-01-03 00:00:01 |        63745228801 |        63745228801 |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```